# HashMap in Java does not work?

Tags: java, hashmap

Here is my code:

```
double getRevenue(KeywordGroupKey key) {
    Double r = revenueMap.get(key);
    System.out.println(key + "\t" + key.hashCode());
    for (KeywordGroupKey other : revenueMap.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(other.toString() + "\t" + other.hashCode());
        if(other.equals(key))
            System.out.println("equals here...");
    }
    if(r == null)
        r = 0.0;
    return r;
}
```

and here is the output:

```
优惠打折，优惠券|"优惠券"  955095524
brand+点评团购|大众点评 726983298
brand-品牌词相关|团购网站大全  -713384514
brand-品牌词|点评网   2029153675
brand+点评团购|大众点评网    261410621
优惠打折，优惠券|"优惠券"  955095524
equals here...
```

So it is so strange that the value returned by the method is null, why dose this happen? Since there is a key in the revenueMap has the same hash code and equals with argument key.
Below is the current state of the revenueMap and key:

```
{brand+点评团购|大众点评=28.0, brand-品牌词相关|团购网站大全=49.9, brand-品牌词|点评网=21.0, brand+点评团购|大众点评网=167.0, 优惠打折，优惠券|"优惠券"=9.9}
优惠打折，优惠券|"优惠券"
```

Comment: could you please post the reproducible unit of code

Comment: There is no easy way to post that because I add key-value pairs to the map when parsing a big log file and there is too much code.

Comment: Maybe the value for that key (which exists) is `null`? You can do `revenueMap.put("优惠券", null)`

Comment: No, there dose exist a double value and the method containsKey() also returns false, that's why I am so confused.

Comment: what does `revenueMap.containsKey(key)` return? Did you properly implement `equals` and `hashCode` for `KeywordGroupKey`?

Comment: take an iterator for keyset. then try getting values

Comment: System.out.println(revenueMap) please

Comment: Try entryset and print each key and its value.

Comment: @hage: good question, while the output suggests that it's implemented correctly enough, it's possible that `KeywordGroupKey` is mutable and was modified *after* beeing used as a key in the Map!

Comment: Post the complete code for `KeywordGroupKey`.  If `equals()` and `hashcode()` are not correctly overridden you can get the behavior you describe.

Comment: Or if the hashcode() is mutable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that `KeywordGroupKey` is mutable and the key in question was modified after it was used as the key of the hash map.

If that's the case, then the key is in the wrong "bucket" in the `HashMap` and the `get()` method (or `containsKey()` method) will never find it (but iterating over the keys and/or entries *will* find it!).

For example, assuming there's a property `foo` in your class and that property is relevant to your `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods. The following code would "break" the `HashMap`:

```
KeywordGroupKey key = ...
revenueMap.put(key, someValue);
key.setFoo("differentValue");
Double result = revenueMap.get(key); // will return nothing!
Double result = revenueMap.get(originalValueOfKey); // will *also* return nothing!
```

Comment: If the two objects are equal, how can they get different hash code? And I do get the same hash code in my question above:955095524. @Joachim Sauer

Comment: I'm saying that the key you inserted into the `HashMap` has *changed* **after** you used it as the key in the map, that would "break" the map.